# Select Statement Returning Multiple of Same Dates

Tags: sql-server, date, case

I am having issues with a select statement that is returning multiple dates that are the same.

I will start off with the tables that I have:

Calendar: Very basic, just a table that contains all of the days for the next 20 years.

```
PKDate
------
2015-04-01
2015-04-02
2015-04-03
etc...
```

DaysWorked: This table contains all days that all equipment in the company has worked. There is a foreign key constraint to the `PKDate` in calendar to the `DayWorked` in this table.

```
DayWorked  |  Unit
----------------
2015-04-01 | 102
2015-04-05 | 103
```

Event: This is the table that is behind our scheduling system. This holds all of the days that can be booked off as days off. The use can select a start and end date for the days off or vacation. There are no foreign key constraints in this table.

```
Name     |  EventStart  |  EventEnd  |  Unit  
-----------------------------------------
Days Off | 2015-04-06   | 2015-04-08 | 103
Days Off | 2015-04-03   | 2015-04-09 | 102
```

This is the stored procedure that I am executing:

```
select distinct PKDate as 'Date', case when PKDate not in (select DayWorked
                                             from DaysWorked
                                             where Unit='124')
                                then 'AVAILABLE'
                                else ''
                                end
                                as 'Available',

                    case when PKDate in (select DayWorked
                                        from DaysWorked
                                        where Unit='124')
                    then 'WORKED'
                    else ''
                    end
                    as 'Worked',

                    case when PKDate between E.EventStart and DATEADD(day, -1, E.EventEnd)
                         and E.ResourceID='124'
                    then UPPER(E.Name)
                    else ''
                    end
                    as 'Schedule'
from Event E
full outer join Calendar C
on PKDate between E.EventStart and E.EventEnd
where PKDate between '2015-04-01' and GETDATE()
order by PKDate asc
```

This stored procedure almost works as planned. I want the result of the procedure to show every day in the calendar in one column (Date), then display if the equipment was available (available), if the equipment worked (worked), and if the equipment was booked for days off or vacation (Schedule).

What is happening when I run the procedure is the date displays more than once for the same date. An example is shown in the photo below:

[image]

For the days Aprilt 13th to April 16th the days are repeated. I believe these days are repeated because I have something for those days in the Event table, but I do no know why the day displays twice. How can I get these days to only display once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select C.PKDate
  ,case when not exists ( select * from DaysWorked where Unit = '124' and DayWorked = C.PKDate )
    and not exists ( select * from Event E where E.EventStart <= C.PKDate and E.EventEnd >= C.PKDate and E.ResourceID = '124')  
    then 'AVAILABLE' else '' end as Available
  ,case when exists ( select * from DaysWorked where Unit = '124' and DayWorked = C.PKDate ) then 'WORKED' else '' end as Worked
  ,isnull((select max(E.Name) from Event E where E.EventStart <= C.PKDate and E.EventEnd >= C.PKDate and E.ResourceID = '124' ), '') as Schedule
from Calendar C
where C.PKDate between '2015-4-1' and getdate()
order by c.PKDate
```

Comment: For the date this is what I am looking for. But it does not include the Schedule column for the 13-16

Comment: This works out, but additionally when the column `Schedule` has data in it, the `Available` column cannot have anything in it.

Comment: OK I added an extra clause to the Available column to make it blank if there are any events scheduled

Comment: Oh I see, you are using the same clause to check for the days off. I could have got that last part ahha. Thank you for your help. I have been stuck on this forever!!!